# Canonical Predual of Lipschitz spaces

Tags: lipschitz-functions

Suppose $M$ is a subset of a Banach space $X$.

[Here](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/collect2004.pdf), page $179$, the author defined Lipschitz-free space $\mathcal{F}(M)$ to be the canonical predual of the space of Lipschitz functions Lip$(M)$, i.e. the closed linear span of the point evaluations
$$\delta_M(x)(f)=f(x), x \in M$$
in Lip$(M)^*$.

Question: I don't understand the definition of the Lipschitz-free space. Can anyone give some examples so that I can understand it?

Comment: (A rather late response, finding this from google): Chapter 10 of Ostrovskii's book 'Metric Embeddings: Bilipschitz and coarse embeddings into Banach spaces' contains a slightly different definition of the Lipschitz Free space and contains computations. If you're interested I can give more details, but his book is going to be better than me regurgitating.

Comment: @JamesKilbane: I couldn't find the book on the internet. Can you give more details on it?

Comment: Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space. We define a **molecule** on $X$ to be a finitely supported function such that $\sum_{x \in X} m(x) = 0$, and define the molecule $m_{pq} = 1_p - 1_q$. For a molecule define $\|m\|_{LF} = \inf \{ \sum |a_i| d(p_i, q_i) : m = \sum a_i m_{p_i q_i} \}$. The Lipschitz Free space is then the completion of all molecules with the $\|.\|_{LF}$ norm.

Comment: http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/sm2003c.pdf

This paper (also) contains a definition of the free space, see definition 1.1. This definition just expounds on what 'canonical predual' means in this context.

Comment: I also suggest consulting the chapter 2 from the book "Lipschitz Algebras", by Nik Weaver. There the Arens-Eells space (which is another name for the Lipschitz-free space) is presented with some geometric intuition, in connection to Lip(M).